# plotting maps using OSM or other shapefiles and matplotloib for standardized report

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, gdal, matplotlib-basemap, geopandas

We are developing a standardized report for our activities. The last graph I need is to display the geographic area of the activities (there are close to 100 locations).

The output for these reports is PDF letter or A4 size

The report is a mplotlib figure, where:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.5, 11))

rect0 = 0, .7,, 0.18, 0.3
rect1 = .3, .7, .18, .3
rect2 = .8, .29, .2, .7
rect3 = 0, 0, .8, .4

ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect0)
ax2 = fig.add_axes(rect1)
ax3 = fig.add_axes(rect2)
ax4 = fig.add_axes(rect3)
```

The contents and layout for axes 1-3 are settled and work great.  However ax4 is where the map contents would be displayed (ideally).

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
map1 = Basemap(llcrnrlon=6.819087, llcrnrlat=46.368452, urcrnrlon=6.963978,
               urcrnrlat=46.482906, resolution = 'h', projection='tmerc',
               lon_0=6.88, lat_0=46.42, ax=4)

map1.readshapefile('a valid shape file that works') #<----- this is the sticking point


map1.draw(insert locator coordinates)
plt.savefig(report to be inserted to document)
plt.show()
```

However I have not been successful in obtaining a shape file that works from open street maps or GIS.

Nor have I identified the correct process to transform the data from openstreetmaps.

Nor have I identified the process to extract that information from the OSM/xml document or the transformed GeoJSON document.

Ideally I would like to grab the bounding box information from openstreetmaps and generate the map directly.

What is the process to get a shapefile that works with the .readshapefile() call?

Or alternatively how do I get the defined map into a Matplotlib axes ?

Answer (score 2):

It might be easiest to use the `cartopy.io.img_tiles` module, which will automatically pull the OSM tiles for use with `cartopy`. Using the pre-rendered tiles would negate the trouble of handling and styling individual shapefiles/XML.

See the [cartopy docs](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/eyja_volcano.html) on using these tiles within `cartopy`.

Comment: Thanks will give that a try.